# Error upgrading Magento from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.0.1: called getAllOptions() on a non-object app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 478

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, configuration, error, upgrade, third-party-module

I'm trying to update from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.0.1

I tried to update from Magento Connect and by ./mage scripts.
Then I found [this roadmap](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee11302-ce18-install-upgrade) and today morning I also tried this way.

By all the ways, when I call the URL of my site I get **immediately** a blank page and this error in the apache log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getAllOptions() on a non-object in /home/MYSITE/19_www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 478
```

Searching the web someone speak about a problem with Aitoc extensions which should be updated.
This could be my case so in the morning I also try to delete all Aitoc and AdjustWare modules by **removing folders** in /app/code/... and removing xml files from /app/etc/modules.
After that I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Autoload' not found in /home/MYSITE/19_www/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 6
```

So It seems that Aitoc modules are anyway loaded or requested.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Have you cleared cache?

Comment: clear cache and check

Comment: With the last attempt (following the roadmap) the var/cache is not created yet.

Comment: What does your local.xml look like? Standard?

Comment: @DouglasRadburn the local.xml is standard.

Comment: I'd be tempted to contact AITOC regarding this issue

Comment: Ben Lessani of Sonassi has posted [this checklist](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/38458/18509) for ensuring full deletion of modules and specifically discusses Aitoc's unique formats.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have local copies of core files which will make it tough to upgrade. `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php` is mentioned in one of the error messages that you have posted.

What I would suggest is check all the local core files so that you know what modifications you have made and why. Make a note of these as you will need to re-make these changes later on. Then simply remove all the files under `/code/local/Mage` then you should have a "clean" install of 1.9 that is working, if all extensions install are compatibly.

After you have a clean version of 1.9 then I would suggest re-making all the modifications you have made under local, but try to use rewrites and events where possible rather the coping the complete file under the local code pool.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your app/etc/modules directory and rename any of the xml files that have to do with AITOC you will find that your error will stop. I would then recommend not using AITOC as their re-writes usually cause havoc on websites.

I will open just backup my xml to a different directory for testing, then move them back one at a time to confirm that you have found the correct one.

Aitoc will also write to you var directory and you need to make sure it is writable and of course clear you cache!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to fix it (It worked for me after lot of research):

```
chmod 644 app/etc/config.xml
chmod 755 app/etc
chmod 755 app/etc/modules

rm -rf var/cache/* var/session/*
php shell/indexer.php --reindexall
```